# Concatenate Azure CDN Rule Variables

Tags: azure, redirect, iis, azure-cdn

### The Issue

I have read through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-http-variables) and I cannot seem to find any reference to variable concatenation...

I am trying to add a URL Redirect rule where the destination is the following:

```
https://%{host}%{request_uri}
```

When I try to save the rule, I get the following error:

> > URL Redirect: The variable %{hostrequest_uri} does not exist.

This may well be a bug in the Azure platform (wouldn't surprise me...). If this is a bug, then is there a way in which I can get around it? Can I edit the XML manually?

If this is not a bug then what am I doing wrong?

### What I have tried

Aside from the above, I have also tried the following:

```
https://%{host}/%{request_uri}
```

This results in:

```
https://example.com//foobar // note the double slash
```

Worst case scenario, I believe there is a way to manipulate the `%{request_uri}` to remove the leading slash and therefore the above will work but I haven't tested this yet.

The most frustrating thing about all of this is that it takes 4 hours (sometimes more!!!!) in order to test each configuration.

### Update

I believe the following will fix my issue (I will find out in 4+ hours...). Nevertheless, I want to keep this question open as I am intrigued to know how variables are meant to be concatenated regardless.

```
https://%{host}/%{request_uri:1}
```

### Update 2

The above solution did not work, despite following the documentation to the letter... Typical Microsoft rubbish!

I have managed to get it working like so:

```
https://%{host}/%{request_uri#/}
```

The above trims the leading slash off the `%{request_uri}` if it exists.

Whilst this now works, it still doesn't explain why the other bits don't so I will leave this question open.

Comment: Hi man, you save my day. I am whole day yesterday facing the same issue. So annoing to follow the documentation and does not work. And I was waiting 12 hours for approval of the rule but at the end - nothing. I saw some comment there, I think it is manually reviewd thatswhy I let also one comment to the documentation with link to the example down: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-http-variables#example

Hopefully someone will check this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exact the same, but I had somewhere the feeling that the manual reviewers are doing something wrong. Thatswhy I write in the comment of my rule that according documentation it should work. And Voila! They let it indeed. Now it is active and works :D :D :D

[image: HTML Patterns]

**EDIT:**
I am really not joking. The first time when I submitted my patterns were exact like yours, then I got it rejected and there were added the first comment that %{request_uri:1} is not valid (as you can see on the picture)

After that I apply my own comment bellow it and send exact the same again - and it worked. Here the whole screen where you can see that it is active:

[image]

Comment: I highly highly highly doubt that Microsoft/Verizon are **manually** reviewing each and every rule that is submitted to each CDN! I know Microsoft do not understand anything about user experience, and are incapable of writing intuitive software nowadays, but this would be one step too far, even for them. The reason it takes so long will simply be down to propagation. This is still absurd considering other CDN providers are able to propogate their changes almost instantly but oh well, that's Microsoft for you... The reason the above solution works is because it is correct!

Comment: That said, I have no idea why it didn't work for me... I really don't want to believe that Mircrosoft are manually reviewing each rule. It wouldn't surprise me but gees, talk about terrible processes... This company was once revolutionary... The solution in my last update works absolutely fine so I would use that instead

Comment: I'm afraid I can't accept this as the answer as essentially you have just taken the content from my question. I am specifically looking for someone to explain how to concatenate variables in Azure CDN. The solutions I posted are simply workarounds for the interim

Comment: @BenCarey According to this issue, the approval is indeed a manual process: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/13983#issuecomment-416395573

I suppose that the support is somewhere in Philippines or China, because it takes quite fast time when I apply CDN rule between 5AM and 2PM CET Time, which is the working time in east asia. And it took more than 12 hours yesterday when I apply at 3:30PM

Comment: I am speechless... I am only using Azure because of my current client's requirements, I am usually an AWS guy. I have been constantly shocked at how appallingly abysmal Microsoft's services are (not just Azure). There are various reasons why it doesn't surprise me at all, but I won't go into this here. Seriously though, this is just embarassing for what was once one of the most innovative companies on the planet...